# After changing Maricurial url in hgrc, jenkins stuck on pull

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, tortoisehg

My repository url was changed so I updated hgrc file with new url. I also updated new url in jenkins job.

Now when I am building the job, it hangs with the following output

-----------------Console Output-------------------

```
Started by user user123 
Building in workspace D:\jenkins\jobs\api\workspace 
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" showconfig paths.default 
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" pull --rev branch
```

And it will never move forward. If i run the same command on cmd

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" pull --rev branch
```

It works fine with following output

```
pulling from ssh://repos-url/repos-name 
no changes found
```

But jenkins hangs on this command. Need some help to move forward.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my question that I recently changed repository url. The issue was that new server's key was not cached in the registry where jenkins was hosted.

Resolution:

I logged in to the administrator account(same account used by jenkins) on my server through RDP and on the other side I started building the job in jenkins. When the console output came to this line

`[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" pull --rev branch`

RDP window showed me an alert which was

[Putty Security Alert](http://hpc.ucla.edu/hoffman2/access/putty/putty_alert.jpg)

I pressed Yes and I saw jenkins console is now progressing and build was successful after that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me more a jenkins configuration question than a mercurial one :)
Are you talking about the identical clone of the repository? Does the jenkins user have read permissions on the repository it pulls from? Is it configured to pull via ssh, too and does it have the necessary ssh credentials? Or, if pulling via http, is hgweb running on the repo or another webserver to support hg?

Also, unless your project is called 'api', the URL looks strange to me: Jenkins (by default) has its clones in /jenkins-home-directory/jobs/projectname/workspace